# How I get the real median (5.5) from this?

Tags: rust

The result of this code is 6 but the correct answer is 5.5

I'm trying to get the median of the vector of numbers from 1 to 10.

```
fn vector_median(vector: &mut Vec<i32>) -> f64 {
    vector.sort();
    if (vector.len()) % 2 == 0 {
        return f64::from(vector[vector.len() / 2]);
    } else {
        let numbers = (vector[vector.len() / 2], vector[(vector.len() / 2) + 1]);
        (f64::from(numbers.0) + f64::from(numbers.1)) / 2.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vector1 = vec![1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 10];
    let median = vector_median(&mut vector1);

    println!("{:?}", vector1);

    println!("La media es {median}");
}
```

I'm hoping for a result a float number f64, specifically 5.5 with that vector.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The even/odd check is backwards.

- If there's an odd number of elements then you can simply return the middle one.

  ```
  [1, 2, 3]
      ^
  ```
- If there's an even number then you want to average the two closest to the middle.

  ```
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
      ^^^^
  ```

Comment: Yep. my bad, there was another mistake, already corrected.